# Jetsam kills WebGL application on iOS

Tags: ios, memory, webgl

I am currently struggling with memory management inside a webgl application on the web, on iOS only.

I keep getting the following error message :

> Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[0xa7c1]' was killed by jetsam.

I understand that [Jetsam is the system process responsible for memory management](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-iOS-jetsam-and-how-does-it-exactly-work), but the crash occurs while the browser uses around 25% of the device's RAM, which is not that high. I don't have any other open application while running my webGL content. What I don't understand is what *[Taun Chapman](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-iOS-jetsam-and-how-does-it-exactly-work#nsgHFq)* said :

> Jetsam monitors memory use and kills applications which are not good memory citizens. A good memory citizen is an application which is willing to give back memory when asked and does not keep asking for more memory.

Well, the app needs more memory in a short time (when unzipping 3D models using workers), I can't continue my app without it! And it crashed at these particular times.

Moreover, I think I have some memory leaks in my app, [according to Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) I am currently trying to fix. But the browser itself seems to have some leaks too. Thus, fixing mine will just delay the inevitable.

I know the following question is odd, or inappropriate, but do you know if the jetsam "limit" can be increased ? Or if you can add an exception on the currently running WebGL app ?

For your information, I use the [Three.js WebGL library](https://threejs.org/) and the [zip.js library](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) to compress my 3D models.

Yes, I've already read the following question : [Why does simple website crash on mobile (iOS Safari and Chrome, at least)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872344/why-does-simple-website-crash-on-mobile-ios-safari-and-chrome-at-least), but the problem does not come from my CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 10.3.2 version of iOS (released the 15th of May) made Jetsam less aggressive, or at least, the memory is better handled.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207798