# webkit-backface-visibility crashes safari and chrome (IOS)

Tags: ios, css, safari, crash, webkit

I've been working on a new responsive website, and when I start testing in on IPad, I found that it was crashing consistently (tested on IOS 6, IOS 7 and IOS 7.1.1).

After a few hours, I found that what was causing the crash was this CSS instruction:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I was able to create a sample on jsfiddle that replicates this issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/CBqCH/6/

In our case, we were using that style on a listing page, that has for ex: 500 items..

Is this a known issue? Or am I 'styling' it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your css/fiddle its like your adding this like this:

```
*{ -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

Or in other words you are **adding it on all the divs**...

NEVER target all elements (of course it will crash if you're calling multiple), only the ones you need to.

But if not this it seems, that it is common using these css on iOS:

[Mobile Safari on iOS crashes on big pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831429/mobile-safari-on-ios-crashes-on-big-pages)

http://www.dimshik.com/ios-7-runs-out-of-memory-when-using-webkit-transform/