# force Bootstrap to use jQuery instead of CSS transitions

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to force Bootstrap to use its `transition.js` and jQuery animations, instead of CSS3 `transition`? I use lot of animations, and it fails on iPad.

Comment: "fails on iPad" Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: won't get much help without being a lot more specific

Comment: @Mooseman: OH! Page crashes then reloads. It's not related to question. I want to replace jQuery animation with transition.

Comment: More information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11833285/501134

Comment: @kikio Which is it? `CSS3 => jQuery` or `jQuery => CSS3`?

Comment: `CSS3 => jQuery` needed...

Answer (score 0):

A simple, albeit hackish, way to this would be to [open transitions.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js) and replace

```
  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }

    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }
```

with

```
function transitionEnd(){ return false; }
```

If you're using minified Bootstrap, find the same function and replace its contents with `return false;`.

---

This causes `$.support.transition` to be set to `false`, which causes Bootstrap to think the browser does **not** support CSS3 animations. ***BEWARE***, however, as doing this ***will*** hurt performance on many devices.