# Check active style sheet from js code (check cookie for active style sheet)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a code for writing/reading cookie for active style sheet (CSS switcher):

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

and two lines in html:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
   <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="darkmode.css" title="darkmode">
   <script src="styleswitcher.js"></script>
```

I want to set checkbox to “checked” if darkmode.css is active.

The question is:
**How I can check if darkmode.css is active in single line JavaScript code from external .js file according listed code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

local storage is a best method for saving data. etc:

set:

```
localStorage.setItem("style", "dark");
```

get:

```
var style = localStorage.getItem("style");
```

example:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("style")==="dark"){
    $("html").addClass("dark");
}else{
    $("html").addClass("light");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you advice how to check active style according listed code?

Comment: you can add all theme styles in main.css file and just change name of class in body or html tag. this method is fast in changing style and theme and not have delay

Comment: Is it saves like cookie? For how long data in localStorage stores?

Comment: please see https://ethermine.org/ site and change theme top right on page and check local storage in inspect element.

Comment: ...but on iPhone 4s browser crashes when apply class to body.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831429/mobile-safari-on-ios-crashes-on-big-pages

Comment: Thanks. The core of problem found.